# Entity Framework losing connection data after creation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, connection-string, ef-database-first

I have a .edmx model that I have been using for years. After a VS update a few months ago every time that I try to update the model from the database (after a new table has been created or something else has been changed in the db) I have to recreate the connection by manually entering address, username, etc...

In the past I was used to just right-click the model, select Update model from database and then this dialog was shown

[image: Update wizard Choose your database objects window]

But now I get this window here
[image: Update wizard Choose your data connection]

What puzzles me is that connection info are correct, but if I try to click Next the dialog gets closed and nothing happens. Selecting No or Yes in the question doesn't have any effect on this behaviour.
In order to update my model I need to click New Connection and enter all the connection parameters again. Every time.

I have also tried to create a brand new edmx model, but I get the same problem when I try to update it.

I'm using EF 6.0 and VS 2022.